# one to one mapping between the floor function and the Riemann prime counting function

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-number-theory

We have the following 'transform' of a real valued, piecewise continuous function $f(x)$ :

$$T[f(x)]=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}_{+}}f\left(\frac{x}{\Lambda _{n}} \right )\frac{1}{n!}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}f(u_{i}) \right )\Theta^{n-1}_{u_{n}}f(u_{n})\frac{d\Lambda_{n}}{\Lambda _{n}}$$

where :

$$\Lambda_{n} =\prod_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}$$
$$d\Lambda_{n}=\prod_{n=1}^{n}du_{i}$$
$$\Theta_{u_{k}}=u_{k}\frac{d}{du_{k}}$$

and we wish to recover $f(x)$ from $T[f(x)]$.

What kind of mathematics should be used to study this problem?

### EDIT:

$$J(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\ln\zeta(s)\frac{x^{s}}{s}ds$$

where $J(x)$ is the Riemann prime counting function . 
 The above relation is the well known Perron's formula for Dirichlet series. This induced me to express $\zeta(s)$ as an exponential series expansion in terms of $\ln\zeta(s)$:

$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\ln\zeta(s))^{n}}{n!}$$

Applying Perron's formula :

$$\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\alpha-i\infty}^{\alpha+i\infty}\zeta(s)\frac{x^{s}}{s}ds=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}(\ln\zeta(s))^{n}\frac{x^{s}}{s}ds$$

The first two terms corresponding to $n=0,n=1$ are trivial. The other terms starting at $n=2$ could be done using Mellin convolution. Namely, if two functions, say $F(s)$ and $G(s)$ are given by:

$$F(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)x^{-s-1}dx$$ 
$$G(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)x^{-s-1}dx$$ 
  then the following holds :

$$F(s)G(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\bigstar g(x) x^{-s-1}dx$$
 Where the star stands for Mellin convolution, and is defined by :
 $$f(x)\bigstar g(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f\left( \frac{x}{u}\right)g(u)\frac{du}{u}$$

Another property of the Mellin transform we will need is that, if a function, say $h(x)$ is a Mellin inverse of of $H(s)$, then :
 $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}sH(s)x^{s}ds=x\frac{d}{dx}h(x)$$

Using these facts about the Mellin transform, we can evaluate the integrals :

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}(\ln\zeta(s))^{n}\frac{x^{s}}{s}ds=J(x)\bigstar \left( x\frac{d}{dx}J(x)\right)^{\bigstar n-1}$$

Where the star and the power $n-1$ mean repeated convolution for $n-1$ times .

Furthermore, the Mellin convolution has the property :

$$\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{n}(f(x)\bigstar g(x))=f(x)\bigstar \left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{n}g(x)=g(x) \bigstar\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{n}f(x) $$
Therefore :

$$\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty}\zeta(s)\frac{x^{s}}{s}ds$$

Therefore :

$$\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor=1+  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{J(x)^{\bigstar n}}{(n+1)!} \bigstar \left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{n}J(x)$$

This relation could be given more explicitly by:

$$\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}_{+}}J\left(\frac{x}{\Lambda _{n}} \right )\frac{1}{n!}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}J(u_{i}) \right )\Theta^{n-1}_{u_{n}}J(u_{n})\frac{d\Lambda_{n}}{\Lambda _{n}}$$
where :

$$\Lambda_{n} =\prod_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}$$
$$d\Lambda_{n}=\prod_{n=1}^{n}du_{i}$$
$$\Theta_{u_{k}}=u_{k}\frac{d}{du_{k}}$$

We define the following operator acting on a distribution $f(x)$:
$$T[f(x)]=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}_{+}}f\left(\frac{x}{\Lambda _{n}} \right )\frac{1}{n!}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}f(u_{i}) \right )\Theta^{n-1}_{u_{n}}f(u_{n})\frac{d\Lambda_{n}}{\Lambda _{n}}$$

if $f(x)$ is given by :

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty}\ln g(s)\frac{x^{s}}{s}ds$$

then, the following holds:

$$T[f(x)]=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} g(s)\frac{x^{s}}{s}ds$$

The plan here is to investigate the geometric and algebraic properties of the mapping above. One thing that comes in mind is trying to find an inverse of the operator $T[f(x)]$, such that : 
$$T^{-1}T[f(x)]=f(x)$$

assuming such an operator exists, and applying the operator to $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor$:

$$T^{-1}[\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor]=J(x)$$
 and the prime counting function $\pi(x)$ could be given by:

$$\pi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}T^{-1}\left[\left \lfloor x^{1/n} \right \rfloor\right]$$

Comment: If that is a multivariable integral and $y$ is a vector, then what does $e^y$ mean?

Comment: I wonder what kind of math was used to arrive at this problem...

Comment: I don't understand the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental prime-power counting function $\pi(x)$ and the Riemann prime-power counting function $J(x)$ (also referred to as $\Pi(x)$) defined in (1) and (2) below can be expressed in terms of the floor function $\lfloor x\rfloor$ as illustrated in (3) and (4) below where $b_{\pi}(n)$ and $b_J(n)$ are the Möbius transforms of $a_{\pi}(n)$ and $a_J(n)$ (see [Möbius transformation - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula) and [Weisstein, Eric W. "Möbius Inversion Formula." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusInversionFormula.html)).

**(1)** $\quad\pi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x a_{\pi}(n)\,,\quad a_{\pi}(n)=\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & n\in \mathbb{P} \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}\quad$(see https://oeis.org/A010051)

**(2)** $\quad J(x)=\sum_\limits{n=1}^x a_J(n)\,,\quad a_J(n)=\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & n=1 \\
 \frac{\Lambda (n)}{\log (n)} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$

**(3)** $\quad\pi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x b_{\pi}(n)\,\lfloor \frac{x}{n}\rfloor\,,\quad b_{\pi}(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n}a_{\pi}(d)\,\mu(\frac{n}{d})=\sum\limits_{d|n}\mu(d)\,a_{\pi}(\frac{n}{d})\,,\\$ $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$(see https://oeis.org/A143519)

**(4)** $\quad J(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x b_J(n)\,\lfloor \frac{x}{n}\rfloor\,,\quad b_{J}(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n}a_{J}(d)\,\mu(\frac{n}{d})=\sum\limits_{d|n}\mu(d)\,a_{J}(\frac{n}{d})$

Formulas (3) and (4) above are the basis of the Fourier series representations of $\pi(x)$ and $J(x)$ (see [Fourier Series for Prime Counting Functions](https://www.primefourierseries.com/)).

I believe the Fourier series representation of $U'(x)=\delta(x+1)+\delta(x-1)$ is probably of more significant importance because it can be used to evaluate Mellin convolutions such as $g(y)=\int_0^\infty\delta(x-1)\,g\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\,\frac{dx}{x}$ to derive new formulas for a variety of functions thereby providing new insights into functions and their relationships (see my answer to my own question [What is Relationship Between Distributional and Fourier Series Frameworks for Prime Counting Functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2380164)).